# Prolog get the number of nested list + 1 where an element is into a list

Tags: prolog

I'd like to return the depth level or number of nested list where certain element is. Also as condition the list doesn't have repeated elements. I am trying to understand this solution where I have two main doubts:

```
profundidad([],_,0):-!.
profundidad([A],A,1):-!.
profundidad([A|_],A,1):-!.
profundidad([H|_],A,N):-
    profundidad(H,A,R),N is R+1.
profundidad([_|X],A,N):-
    profundidad(X,A,N),!.
```

The correct output would be:

```
profundidad([2,3,4,5,[[6]],10],6,X).
X = 3
```

First, why we do put the cut operator ! from 1-3 statements? I know it prevents compiler from considering later statements when a solution is found.
Second, how we could read 4th and 5th cases in natural language?

The depth of an element A when the list is splitted by the head H and the rest _, is equal to the number R of steps plus 1.

```
profundidad([H|_],A,N):-
    profundidad(H,A,R),N is R+1.
```

And those two sentences I think they are the same as previous ones but to go forward into the list:

```
profundidad([_|X],A,N):-
    profundidad(X,A,N),!.
```

Plus, I am doubting now about why to not put [] into recursive called to:

```
profundidad(X,A,N),!.
```

I think it is to go deep into the nested lists but I am not sure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to avoid cuts when possible, in the following rewrite and simplification the test `H\=A` make the three clauses *disjunctive*.

```
profundidad([A|_],A,1).
profundidad([H|_],A,N):-
    % H\=A,
    profundidad(H,A,R),
    N is R+1.
profundidad([H|T],A,N):-
    H\=A,
    profundidad(T,A,N).
```

The second clause doesn't need the test, since it goes down a level in the list, meaning it will succeed when it's a list, and then cannot unify with the target element anyway. For clarity it could stay there - it doesn't harm.

If your Prolog has dif/2, you could use that instead of (\=)/2, depending on your requirements about the generality (WRT variables instantiation) of the solution.

Comment: Thank you CapelliC for helping me with this topic. I struggled trying to figure out what was \= operator for and it looks like it means not ( A = B), so then it is disjuntion as you say. I think first case is the trivial one, when we reach a number which is at the same level of the outer list; the second means to go deep into the nested lists and the third one is to go forward on the outer list because of passed A and actual H are different. Howeever I struggle with: H\=A, profundidad(H,A,R), because it is strange that if you ask H is defferent than A you use H in the recursive call!

Comment: I attempted to explain in the answer why the test is optional. Clearly, if `profundidad(H,A,R)` succeeds, `H` **must** be a list. Does this help ?

Comment: Yes it helps, because it states that H needs to be a list rather than be compared with the requested A.